# HTML Outlook signature does not display in GMAIL

Tags: html, outlook, signature

I'm hitting my head against a brick wall here.. I've succesfully coded a HTML signature that works well in Outlook to pretty much every provider aside from GMAIL. It's as if gmail strips out the code and just displays broken text with a few tags, and no images.

The code I'm using is for a client and is below:

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<div><span style="color:#626262;"><span style="font-size:12px;"><span style="font-family: arial;"><strong>Steve 

Jobs</strong></span></span><br /><br />
<p style="line-height:30px"><A 
            title=blocked::http://www.themediapeople.london
            href="http://www.tmp.london" target=_blank><IMG 
            id=_x0000_i5 class=image_fix 
            title="blocked::http://www.themediapeople.london&#10;TMP" 
            border=0 alt=TMP src="http://www.love4it.org/portals/0/Users/Logo.jpg" 
            width=300 height=40>

</A>
<br />
<span style="color:#999999;"><span style="font-size: 12px;"><strong><span style="font-family: arial;">Office: 

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;023 24 99 868</span></strong></span><br />
<span style="font-size: 12px;"><strong><span style="font-family: arial;">Mobile:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;07751 775 

489</span></strong></span><br />    
<span style="font-size: 12px;"><strong><span style="font-family: arial;">Web:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<A 

style="COLOR: #999999; TEXT-DECORATION: underline" 

href="http://www.tMP.london">www.tmp.london</a></span></strong></span></span></p>
<span style="color:#999999;"><span style="font-size: 12px;"><strong><span style="font-family: arial;">TMP,&nbsp;59

-61 TMP Garden,&nbsp;London&nbsp;TMPN&nbsp;8LS</span></strong></span></span><br /><br />

<p><A 
            title=blocked::https://www.facebook.com/TMP 
            href="https://www.facebook.com/TMP" target=_blank><IMG 
            id=_x0000_i class=image_fix 
            title="blocked::https://www.facebook.com/TMP&#10;TMP" 
            border=0 alt=TMP src="http://www.love4it.org/Portals/0/Users/FB.jpg" 
            width=40px height=41px>

</A>

<A 
            title=blocked::https://twitter.com/tMP 
            href="https://twitter.com/themediapeople_" target=_blank><IMG 
            id=_x0000_i2 class=image_fix 
            title="blocked::https://twitter.com/tmp&#10;TMP" 
            border=0 alt=TMP src="http://www.love4it.org/Portals/0/Users/TW.jpg" 
            width=40 height=39>

</A>

<A 
            title=blocked::https://www.linkedin.com/company
            href="https://www.linkedin.com/company" target=_blank><IMG 
            id=_x0000_i3 class=image_fix 
            title="blocked::https://www.linkedin.com/company/&#10;TMP" 
            border=0 alt=TMP src="http://www.love4it.org/Portals/0/Users/LN.jpg" 
            width=40 height=40>

</A>

<A 
            title=blocked::https://plus.google.com/tnp
            href="https://plus.google.com/tmp" target=_blank><IMG 
            id=_x0000_i4 class=image_fix 
            title="blocked::https://plus.google.com/tmp&#10;TMP" 
            border=0 alt=TMP src="http://www.love4it.org/Portals/0/Users/GP.jpg" 
            width=40 height=40>

</A>

<A 
            title=blocked::https://www.instagram.com/tmp/
            href="https://www.instagram.com/tmp/" target=_blank><IMG 
            id=_x0000_i5 class=image_fix 
            title="blocked::https://www.instagram.com/tmp/&#10;TMP" 
            border=0 alt=TMP src="http://www.love4it.org/Portals/0/Users/insta.jpg" 
            width=40 height=40>

</A>


<A 
            title=blocked::https://www.google.com
            href="https://plus.google.com/tmp" target=_blank><IMG 
            id=_x0000_i6 class=image_fix 
            title="blocked::https://plus.google.com/tmp&#10;TMP" 
            border=0 alt=TMP src="http://www.love4it.org/Portals/0/Users/GPs.jpg" 
            width=112 height=40>

</A></p>



<span style="color:#999999;"><hr />

<p><span style="font-size: 12px;"><span style="font-family: arial;"><strong>Disclaimer:</strong> This e-mail and any files 

transmitted with it are confidential and are intended solely for the use of the individual or entity to whom they are addressed. If 

you are not the intended recipient or the person responsible for delivering the e-mail to the intended recipient be advised that you 

have received this e-mail in error and that any use, dissemination, forwarding, printing or copying of this e-mail is strictly 

prohibited. The statement and opinions expressed in this mail message are those of the writer, and do not necessarily represent those 

of TMP.</p><br /></span></span></span>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Your code is too large to debug. Try breaking it to small parts and test parts one by one to find out which part is causing the issue.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, no matter how basic the signature gmail removes all formatting. even a signature with just <span style="font-size: 32px;"> Hi </span> and gmail will strip that out. I'm left with what appears to be plain text and a winmail.dat attachment. The thing is this works on every other email account and client, just not gmail... always strips it out and leaves winmail.dat.

Comment: I figured it out... on Exchange server TNEF needed to be turned off. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Turn off TNEF on exchange server. Also adding HTTPS instead of HTTP improved things.